# No matching PlatformTransactionManager bean found for my custom transaction manager

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, transactions, spring-transactions

I have two data sources:

```
spring.datasource.url=url1
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

I use the first for insert/replace in mysql database.

```
spring.second-datasource.url=url2
spring.second-datasource.username=root
spring.second-datasource.password=sa
spring.second-datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

I use the second for sphinx select query.

As I understand I need two different transaction managers for two data sources.

First **databaseTransactionManager**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = ["com.pbnhq.whois.db"],
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "databaseEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "databaseTransactionManager"
)
class DatabaseTransactionManagerConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean("databaseDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    fun databaseDataSource(): DataSource {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build()
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean("databaseEntityManagerFactory")
    fun databaseEntityManagerFactory(
        builder: EntityManagerFactoryBuilder,
        @Qualifier("databaseDataSource") dataSource: DataSource
    ): LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean {
        return builder
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .packages("com.pbnhq.whois.db")
            .persistenceUnit("database")
            .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean("databaseTransactionManager")
    fun databaseTransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("databaseEntityManagerFactory")
        firstEntityManagerFactory: EntityManagerFactory
    ): PlatformTransactionManager {
        return JpaTransactionManager(firstEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Second **sphinxTransactionManager**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = ["com.pbnhq.whois.db"],
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "sphinxEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "sphinxTransactionManager"
)
class SphinxTransactionManagerConfig {
    @Bean("sphinxDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.second-datasource")
    fun sphinxDataSource(): DataSource {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build()
    }


    @Bean("sphinxEntityManagerFactory")
    fun sphinxEntityManagerFactory(
        builder: EntityManagerFactoryBuilder,
        @Qualifier("sphinxDataSource") dataSource: DataSource
    ): LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean {
        return builder
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .packages("com.pbnhq.whois.db")
            .persistenceUnit("sphinx")
            .build();
    }

    @Bean("sphinxTransactionManager")
    fun sphinxTransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("sphinxEntityManagerFactory")
        firstEntityManagerFactory: EntityManagerFactory
    ): PlatformTransactionManager {
        return JpaTransactionManager(firstEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

I have repository **WhoisDB**:

```
@Repository
interface WhoisDB : JpaRepository<WhoisDatabaseElement, Long>, CustomizedWhoisDB {
}
```

**CustomizedWhoisDB**:

```
interface CustomizedWhoisDB {
    fun selectFromIndex(domain: String)
}
```

**CustomizedWhoisDBImpl**:

```
@Component
class CustomizedWhoisDBImpl : CustomizedWhoisDB {
    @Transactional(transactionManager = "sphinxTransactionManager")
    @Query("SELECT FROM whois WHERE MATCH('domain')")
    override fun selectFromIndex(@Param("domain") domain: String) {
    }
}
```

I want to test my select query. I have test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
class SphinxTest {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var repo: WhoisDB

    @Test
    @Transactional(transactionManager = "sphinxTransactionManager")
    fun select() {
        val result = repo.selectFromIndex("example.com")
    }
}
```

But currently I get this error

```
No bean named 'sphinxTransactionManager' available: No matching PlatformTransactionManager bean found for qualifier 'sphinxTransactionManager' - neither qualifier match nor bean name match!
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'sphinxTransactionManager' available: No matching PlatformTransactionManager bean found for qualifier 'sphinxTransactionManager' - neither qualifier match nor bean name match!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.qualifiedBeanOfType(BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.qualifiedBeanOfType(BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.java:95)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.getTransactionManager(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:332)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:198)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:40)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:82)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:132)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I am new with these technologies. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I used [this manual](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases) and tried to add part of my project to it. After it succeeded I repeated it in my project and it started work. I think one of the problem was wrong path to my entity element. And I needed to add this option:

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```